# jQuery AJAX Click DELETE Method Not Firing Consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a an AJAX method that is triggering a DELETE method for the link that is being clicked, but despite having my jQuery work once, I am not reaching the point where the AJAX method is being triggered and can't determine what is wrong with the code. Could it be due to an uncaught syntax error. The onload console.log fires so I know the file is being recognized, but the console.log within the click is not firing. In addition, is this the best way to trigger the DELETE method?

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("Window loaded")
    $('#blog-comment-delete').click(function(){
        var blogId = $(this).data("blog-id");
        var commentId = $(this).data("comment-id");
        var urlPath = '/app/blog/' + blogId + '/comment/' + commentId;
        console.log('Pre-AJAX');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: urlPath,
            success: function(){
                window.location.replace('/app');
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('Deletion Error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**App route using Node.js:**

```
appRoutes.route('/blog/:blogId/comment/:blogCommentId')

    .delete(function(req, res){
        models.BlogComment.destroy({
            where: {
                blogId: req.params.blogId,
                blogCommentId: req.params.blogCommentId,
                userId: req.user.userId
            }
        }).then(function(){
            req.flash('info', 'Comment was successfully deleted.');
            res.send('Comment was deleted.');
        });
    });
```

**Link:**

```
<div class="blog-comments">
    {{#blog_comments}}
            <p id="blog-comment">{{comment}}</p>
            <a href="#" id="blog-comment-delete" data-blog-id="{{blogId}}" data-comment-id="{{blogCommentId}}">Delete</a>
    {{/blog_comments}}
</div>
```

Comment: Could it be that there are multiple elements with this same id `blog-comment-delete`?

Comment: @KeesvanLierop there are. It is used for each comment. Should I use some other identifier that is unique in order for it to accurately trigger?

Comment: Well an id should always be unique and can only be once on the same page, so that could be the conflict. Change this to a classname instead (see my answer)

Comment: @KeesvanLierop that fixed my problem, thank you! I didn't realize the use of ID and Class could impact the jQuery methods

Comment: nice to hear! Just created my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of id's, use classname to use as selectors. Id's are unique and if there ere multiple elements on the same page with the same id, your event listeners will break. So instead do:

```
<div class="blog-comments">
    {{#blog_comments}}
            <p id="blog-comment">{{comment}}</p>
            <a href="#" class="blog-comment-delete" data-blog-id="{{blogId}}" data-comment-id="{{blogCommentId}}">Delete</a>
    {{/blog_comments}}
</div>
```

And your event listener should look like:

```
$('.blog-comments').on('click', '.blog-comment-delete', function(){
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try it like this
1)

```
$('#blog-comment-delete').on('click',function(){
     //Your code
    });
```

2) if 1st not work then:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#blog-comment-delete", function() {
       //Your code
    });
```

3)

```
$('body').delegate('#blog-comment-delete','click',function(){
     //Your code
    });
```